# Pull last appearance for the file numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get only one occurance, and the last one, of each file ID, the way that I am pulling it, even if I supply a FileID, it still returns more than one.

```
SELECT  
            FM.FileNumber, FA.ReceivedDate AS LienSearchOrderDate, 
            FA1.ReceivedDate AS LienSearchReceivedDate, 
            DATEDIFF(dd, FA.ReceivedDate, FA1.ReceivedDate) AS TurnTimeDaysLienSearch, 
            FM.FileID, PC.Name, C.County, P.State, S.Name AS Status, 
            FM.ClientsFileNumber
FROM        dbo.FileMain AS FM 
INNER JOIN  dbo.FilePartnerRel AS FPR ON FM.FileID = FPR.FileID AND FPR.PartnerTypeID = 10011 
INNER JOIN  dbo.PartnerCompany AS PC  ON FPR.PartnerCompanyID = PC.PartnerCompanyID 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.FileActions AS FA     ON FM.FileID = FA.FileID 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.FileActions AS FA1    ON FA.FileID = FA1.FileID 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.ActionDef AS AD       ON FA1.ActionDefID = AD.ActionDefID 
INNER JOIN  dbo.Property AS P         ON FA1.FileID = P.FileID 
INNER JOIN  dbo.County AS C           ON P.CountyID = C.CountyID 
INNER JOIN  dbo.Status AS S           ON FM.StatusID = S.StatusID
WHERE FM.FileNumber = 'PA-22440' 
  and (FM.OpenedDate > '2012-10-01') 
  AND (FA.ActionDefID = 28) 
  AND (FA.ReceivedDate IS NOT NULL) 
  AND (FA.Live = 1) AND (FA1.ActionDefID = 183) 
  AND (FA1.Live = 1)
Group by FA.ReceivedDate, FM.FileNumber, FA1.ReceivedDate, FM.FileID, PC.Name, C.County, 
         P.State, S.Name, FM.ClientsFileNumber
Order by 1
```

I am sure I have some over use of query, but I am trying here.  I can get it to get the bottom occurrence EVER, but I want to have it pull each instance FileNumber.

Here is the output I am getting:

```
FileNumber  LienSearchOrderDate LienSearchReceivedDate  TurnTimeDaysLienSearch  FileID  Name    County  State   Status  ClientsFileNumber
PA-22440    38:37.6 NULL    NULL    16448   NTIS    Pinellas    FL  Cancelled   test
PA-22440    40:08.8 NULL    NULL    16448   NTIS    Pinellas    FL  Cancelled   test
```

and the expected is just the last item, nothing more.

Comment: You should **narrow down the problem** in that query quite a bit yourself. Start by removing most things from the `SELECT`, and then removing the `JOIN`'s one by one where you can to see what happens. As written, we have to dig through the query to look for a possible problem, and, without given example input and expected and actual output, there's sure to be a fair amount of guess-work involved. To clarify, also **give us example input and expected and actual output**.

Comment: Why is the `Order by 1` in there?

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I was just trying new things.

Comment: @Dukeling - I will get expected and actual output in just a second.

Comment: What do you mean by "*even if I supply a FileID*"?  There's no place in here to supply a FileID.

Comment: When you join to other tables, you run the chance of the ON filter causing multiple records to be returned when you only expect 1. Do some research on how one-to-many joins work.  Also, see if adding DISTINCT after your select helps you.  If not, the data should tell you why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query if it is what you need

```
SELECT      FM.FileNumber, FA.ReceivedDate AS LienSearchOrderDate, 
            FA1.ReceivedDate AS LienSearchReceivedDate, 
            DATEDIFF(dd, FA.ReceivedDate, FA1.ReceivedDate) AS TurnTimeDaysLienSearch, 
            FM.FileID, PC.Name, C.County, P.State, S.Name AS Status, 
            FM.ClientsFileNumber
FROM        dbo.FileMain AS FM 
INNER JOIN  dbo.FilePartnerRel AS FPR ON FM.FileID = FPR.FileID AND FPR.PartnerTypeID = 10011 
INNER JOIN  dbo.PartnerCompany AS PC  ON FPR.PartnerCompanyID = PC.PartnerCompanyID 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.FileActions AS FA     ON FM.FileID = FA.FileID 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.FileActions AS FA1    ON FA.FileID = FA1.FileID 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.ActionDef AS AD       ON FA1.ActionDefID = AD.ActionDefID 
INNER JOIN  dbo.Property AS P         ON FA1.FileID = P.FileID 
INNER JOIN  dbo.County AS C           ON P.CountyID = C.CountyID 
INNER JOIN  dbo.Status AS S           ON FM.StatusID = S.StatusID
WHERE FM.FileNumber = 'PA-22440' 
  and (FM.OpenedDate > '2012-10-01') 
  AND (FA.ActionDefID = 28) 
  AND (FA.ReceivedDate IS NOT NULL) 
  AND (FA.Live = 1) AND (FA1.ActionDefID = 183) 
  AND (FA1.Live = 1)
  AND (FA.ReceivedDate = (SELECT MAX(ReceivedDate) FROM FileActions WHERE ActionDefID = 28 AND ReceivedDate IS NOT NULL AND Live = 1 AND FileID = FM.FileID))
Order by FM.FileNumber
```

if you have a primary key in your FileActions table, which i hope you have, use it to match the right record instead of matching it with ReleaseDate. Something like this:

```
AND FA.PrimaryKey = (SELECT TOP 1 PrimaryKey FROM FileActions WHERE FileID = FM.FileID ORDER BY ReleaseDate DESC)
```

Comment: I have changed around the joins, and it still is supplying 2 results.

Comment: Is seems that problem is in this - dbo.FileActions AS FA - i.e. there is two rows in this table for one row in FileMain table. You will notice different values in column 2, which points to the source of your problem.

Comment: I have adjusted it, and it is still is not pulling as intended.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use GROUP BY clause as you are not using any aggregate functions.

Comment: Big question here is - what do you intend to do? Why do you expect to see only the second line while there are two - SQL doesn't know which one is the one you want and therefore returns both. That's JOIN.

Comment: Because I am wanting JUST the latest result of each of these, but I want it to pull the last result of EVERYTHING if I remove the FileNumber limit.

Comment: ok, I think I didn't understand your question before. I will edit my answer and let's see if I understand now ;-]

Comment: Thank you, I only have the FileNumber in there because I am trying to get it to work on one before moving on to everything.

Comment: It now returns nothing at all, even with adding the FileActions PK in there.

Comment: it is really hard to help without seeing the actual database, but I guess you will have to narrow condition in the subquery by adding same stuff you are filtering your main query with. Probably adding Live = 1 and ReceivedDate IS NOT NULL as well